# How can i increase the heap memory for activeMQ inside a docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using [rmohr/activemq](https://hub.docker.com/r/rmohr/activemq) activemq docker image. Right now it is `-Xms64M` `-Xmx1G`. I need to increase it to `-Xms2g` `-Xmx3g`.

I am using docker-compose. Here are the docker-compose.yml file entries:

```
    version: '3'
    services:
      queue:
        image: rmohr/activemq:5.15.6
        ports:
          - "8161:8161"
          - "61616:61616"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up adding the `ACTIVEMQ_OPTS` parameter under environment to resolve this.

Here is what the docker-compose file looks like:

```
version: '3'
  services:
    queue:
      image: rmohr/activemq:5.15.6
      ports:
        - "8161:8161"
        - "61616:61616"    
      environment:
        ACTIVEMQ_OPTS: "-Xms2g -Xmx3g"
```

Here are the logs from activemq

[image: ActiveMQ logs after memory changes]

Answer (score 0):

```
version: "3"
services:
  queue:
    image: rmohr/activemq:5.15.6
    ports:
      - "8161:8161"
      - "61616:61616"
    environment:
        ACTIVEMQ_OPTS_MEMORY: "-Xms2g -Xmx3g"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50' #set the memory and CPU time based on requirement
          memory: 3g
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 2g
```

Please refer [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources) , [Active MQ memory increase](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/it-operations-management/performance-management/3-5/administrating/data-aggregator-administration/modify-the-external-activemq-memory-limit.html) ,[ACTIVEMQ_OPTS_MEMORY environment variable usage](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/9b1eb96b838957cd60541ca5e057567be3f11990/assembly/src/release/bin/env#L33)

Comment: @prashanth_rajendran - your answer addresses how to increase the docker pod resources but the question is specifically for increasing JVM memory pool. In my case the answer suggested by you just increased the POD resources but the activemq was still going out of heap space.